# clicking in a link inside a div loads in new window

Tags: php, javascript, html, login-script

i am trying to make the login form in my website appears in the middle of the page with gray background, so i have done it like that:

```
     <style type="text/css"> 
        #cover5{position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;overflow:hidden;display:none;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:gray;text-align:center}
    #warning{top: 150px;margin:auto;position:relative;width:600px;height:fit-content;background-color:white;color:black;padding:10px; zIndex:20; border: 5px solid #003366;}
        </style
        <div id="cover5" onclick="javascript:cover5();">
                <div id="warning" onclick="javascript:cover5();">
                    <?php include 'SignIn.php'; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
<script>
 function cover5()
            {

                var cover=document.getElementById('cover5');

                if(vis)
                {
                    vis=0;
                    cover.style.display='block';
                }
                else
                {
                    vis=1;
                    cover.style.display='none';
                }
            }
</script>
```

an this the code of the SignIn.php

```
<form id='login' action='SignIn.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8' onsubmit="return valid()">
<fieldset >
<legend>SignIn</legend>
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<label for='username' >Email:</label>
<input type='text' name='email' id='username'  maxlength="50" /> <br />
<label for='password' >Password:</label>
<input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" /> <br />
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Login' /> <br />
<a href='resetPassword1.php'> Forgot/Reset Password? Click Here</a>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**the problem is that when use clicks on Forgot/Reset Password? or enter wrong data everything opens in new window, i have used iframe instead of div however when the use signIn successfully the home page opens in the same iframe, so anyone know how to solve the problem?** 
sorry for the long question :)

Answer (score 0):

inside of the link try setting `target="_self"` so

```
<a href="resetPassword1.php" target="_self">Forgot/Reset Password? Click Here</a>
```

If that doesn't work try it in another browser. Sometimes browsers have default settings that could mess stuff up. Another possible problem may be Javascript somewhere in your site sending your links to new windows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your link:

```
target='_self'
```

so it would look like this:

```
<a href='resetPassword1.php' target='_self'> Forgot/Reset Password? Click Here</a>
```

there are others you can play with too, like to open in new window:

```
target='_blank'
```

hope this helps